Socket io connection problem from postman
I have a Node.js code deployed to Render; it works fine with Socket.IO. However, when I deploy it to my server, it connects to https://xx.io, but https://xx.io/api does not connect
i made this nginx file :
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xx.io;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/xx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/xx.key;

    location /api {
        rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_buffering off;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/api_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/api_error.log debug;
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_buffering off;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/api_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/api_error.log debug;
    }
}

it connect to socket io in https://xx.io but  https://xx.io/api didn't ,how to fix it
